Is there some science behind the cloud color of "electric blue"
I do notice that the bottom of thunderheads have a dark grey blue hue(here in the PNW they do where I live and T-storms are not common but they do happen). And many times when I see a cloud bank approaching with such colors on the bottom of the clouds there is a thunderstorm coming.
So my question is really is this particular color caused by ionized air surrounding an electrically charged cloud? Or is there another explanation for it...
